# python nested loop print spaces between two characters every repeat

Tags: python

[this is the question i am trying to solve](http://i60.tinypic.com/2960u89.png)

i have tried everything to get the spaces to appear between the hashtags but have failed. i don't know what else to do

this is what i have done so far, i found a few ways to get only 1 space between the hashtags, but to have them repeat every time is what i have not been able to do

```
star = 6

for r in range(star):
    for c in range(r - 5):
        print ' ',
    print '##',
    print
```

[this is the output i get](http://i61.tinypic.com/2dre99j.png)

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def hashes(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print '#' + ' '*i + '#'
```

Testing

```
>>> hashes(1)
##

>>> hashes(4)
##
# #
#  #
#   #
```

Comment: This solution only has one single loop. The original question asked for nested loops.

Comment: @mdwhatcott Who cares? I think the original question was simply describing their first attempt, and was simply an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If this solution solves their actual problem, the implementation is not important.

Comment: @Cyber - Yes, you're probably right. And now there is a solution for the OP's first attempt (provided by you) and a solution that matches the specification in the referenced exercise material (provided by me). I think we've both added value here. Kudos for being first on the draw and for having your answer selected.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there are more succinct ways of doing this, but the original question called for nested loops:

```
import sys

inner = 1
for x in range(6):
    sys.stdout.write('#')
    for y in range(inner):
        if y == inner - 1:
            sys.stdout.write('#')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(' ')
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
    inner += 1
```

Output:

```
$ python loops.py
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```